# Error trying to separate an array containing managed object context

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Could anyone please tell me why I am getting this error and why this code isn't working?

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
reason: '-[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x109494750'
```

This is the code with problems:

```
NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSString *dateString = [array valueForKey:@"dateString"];
NSArray *datesArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];//line with problems
```

Comment: if I delete the line with componentsSeparatedByString it doesn't crash and I have a list of dates when I NSLog dateString

Comment: This is dataString just before the line when it crashes: dateString = (
    "31/05/14",
    "29/05/14",
    "30/05/14"
)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `valueForKey:` on array the result will be an `NSArray` containing the result of calling `valueForKey:` on each of it's elements.

So `dateString` is not actually a string it's an instance of `NSArray`, which does not respond to `componentsSeparatedByString:`. You need to index into the array to get the date you want before  calling `componentsSeparatedByString:` on that

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks like it makes sense to change dateString to datesArray in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's an indication that `dateString` isn't a string. When you call `-valueForKey:` on an array, it returns an array. Per [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a):

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

So you're calling a string method on an array. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish by calling `-valueForKey:`. Perhaps you meant `-objectAtIndex:`?

Comment: Thanks for that, the array is already there just waiting to be used!